# Fetch data from Azure EventHub for a time window in Scala using IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I would like to fetch 1 day data from Azure eventhub and apply some logic and copy it to cosmos DB. I am able to fetch the data from eventhub but the data is streaming. I need to fetch data only for a time window (lets say only for one day/ or for 5 hrs).

Below is the code which I tried to fetch data from Azure EventHub.

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs.{ ConnectionStringBuilder, EventHubsConf, EventPosition }
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object FromEventHub{



 val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("FromEventHubToCosmos")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder()
    .setNamespaceName("NAMESPACE_NAME")
    .setEventHubName("EVENTHUB_NAME")
    .setSasKeyName("KEY_NAME")
    .setSasKey("KEY")
    .build

  val currTime = Instant.now
  val ehConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
  .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(currTime.minus(Duration.ofHours(5))))
  .setEndingPosition(EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(currTime))

  val reader =  spark
    .read
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(ehConf.toMap)
    .load()


val newDF = reader.withColumn("Offset", $"offset".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Time (readable)", $"enqueuedTime".cast(TimestampType)).withColumn("Timestamp", $"enqueuedTime".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Body", $"body".cast(StringType)).select("Offset", "Time (readable)", "Timestamp", "Body")

newDF.show()


}
```

I have used setStartingPosition 5hrs before, but in scala data keeps on streaming from eventhub.   I just need data from event hub till the time the code is executed.

1. Is there any way to limit data from event hub using time window or any other ways ?
2. How to manage the data available in data frame to apply some logic.?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue with a Spark job keeping on streaming and not completing. If this helps, the problem was solved by running the code in [Azure Databricks](https://northeurope.azuredatabricks.net) notebook. Strange, but the job completes there. [Databricks Community Edition](https://community.cloud.databricks.com), which is free, would also do.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the stream part and do it in a batch way. (setEndingPosition only work on batch queries like below).

```
  val reader =  spark
    .read
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(ehConf.toMap)
    .load()
```

Comment: yes. my code is with **read** only not **readStream**, forgot to update here. But when I read the data from dataframe i am getting below error which says I am using more than one instance of consumer group at a time. How to resolve this? ```com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ReceiverDisconnectedException: New receiver with higher epoch of '0' is created hence current receiver with epoch '0' is getting disconnected. If you are recreating the receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used.```
@Oksen

Comment: That is another problem then above but,
I think you start from a lower position than eventhub has available. Try setiing a higher startdate or increase the eventhub retention time